# UITableView acting weird in XCode 4

Tags: ios, uitableview, xcode4, gradient, xcode3to4

I created an application in XCode 3 and my tableviews work great when I run the app on my phone or the simulator, but when I open the project in XCode 4, my tableViews appear with a gradient over them. Could you tell me what's wrong?

Comment: is the tableview XIB or programmatically created ? There is no reason for this to occur unless you do some weird things with, can you add a piece of your code for us to see ?

Comment: We will need more info for this. Post some code blocks, screenshots, etc. something that can help us identifying the problem.

Comment: Yes the tableview is created on the xib file, however the cells are created using a UITableViewCell. Actually there are two types, depending on which page you are... The code is as follows for loading the cells                                                             `if (pageNumber == 0) {
   [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"OrderTableViewPeopleCell" owner:self options:nil];
  } else {
   [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"OrderTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
  }
  
  cell = orderTableViewCell; 
  
  self.orderTableViewCell = nil;`